# Naive Bayes For Regression

Tags: regression, naivebayes

I was wondering, if I can apply naive bayes, to a regression problem and how  will it be done. I have 4096 image features and 384 text features and, it won't be very bad if I assume independence between them. Can anyone tell me how to proceed?

Answer (score 15):

Naive bayes is used for strings and numbers(categorically)
it can be used for classification so it can be either 1 or 0 nothing in between like 0.5 (regression)

Even if we force naive bayes and tweak it a little bit for regression the result is disappointing; A team experimented with this and achieve not so good results.

Also in wikipedia naivebayes has closeness to logistic regression.

> **Relation to logistic regression**:
>   naive Bayes classifier can be considered a way of fitting a probability model that optimizes the joint likelihood p(C , x), while logistic regression fits the same probability model to optimize the conditional p(C | x).

So now you have two choices, tweak naive bayes formula or use logistic regression.

I say lets use logistic regression instead of reinventing the wheel.

**References:**

Wikipedia:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier#Relation_to_logistic_regression

Naive Bayes Regression Experiment: https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1023%2FA%3A1007670802811.pdf

Comment: Logistic Regression is classification algorithm so it is not useful for regression problem.

Answer (score 5):

Naive bayes doesn't make sense to me as a regression algorithm. Random forest regression might be a better fit for your problem. It should be able to handle mixed text and image features.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and get back to you! Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Can you exlain a bit, why would using naive-bayes like method for regression would be bad?

Comment: Naive bayes is typically used for doing classification problems. I don't see how it would be applied for a regression problem.

Comment: They have used naive bayes for regression.

Comment: @Deven  And that paper says *NB performs poorly* for regression